# Item-specific shipping cost wiith Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a woocommerce-based website, with shipping costs depending on the shipping addresses (it's *2€* per product in Germany, and free for foreign countries).

What I need to do is to add another cost, always depending on the destination country, but set differently for each item (for example, product #1 needs *1€* per product, product #2 needs *0.5€* per product etc.). So I need something I can write in every single product for each shipping location.

How can I set this based on the product and the address?

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin / extension does exactly what you need:
https://www.woothemes.com/products/per-product-shipping/

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll take a look... ;)